# jQuery /hover()/.mousemove() optimization issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mousemove

I'm working on a basic modal example in which the modal would follow the mouse cursor as long as the user was hovering over a certain section.

The issue I'm having is, when going from left to right, the modal lags significantly, as well as triggers the fadeOut() set if the user were to mouse out of the specific section.

Right to left, works seamlessly.

In the fiddle, you can observe the lagginess when moving the mouse over the `<nav>` from top to bottom, as well as notice the solid performance from bottom to top.

If there are any duplicate questions or related articles that you all know of, please point me in the right direction. My searches thus far have been informational but have not adressed this specific issue.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bxLPh/15/).

Thank you all, as always pro advice is warmly welcomed.

Ken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that jquery fires onmouseout event when you add the modal element it gets "focus" and hover events are not firing on your nav element.
I altered your example so that it is wokring much better now, check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rThnm/)

Comment: Ohhhhh, that explains why when moving in the opposite direction of the modal it worked perfectly, thank you much!

Answer (score 3):

Oh awesome, classic example! The problem is that the jQuery thinks you've moused-out once you touch the `section#coming-soon`, so it obviously runs the `fadeOut`...

One way to overcome this is to put the `section#coming-soon` inside the `nav`, that way the script will still think you're inside the `section#coming-soon`, even if you hover over it:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a>Home</a></li>
        <br />
        <li><a>About</a></li>
        <br />
        <li><a>My Work</a></li>
        <br />
        <li><a>Blog</a></li>
        <br />
        <li><a>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <section id="coming-soon">
        <h2>Coming Soon!</h2>
    </section>
</nav>
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gcJuz/1/

Comment: Also a solid approach! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just a few recommendations to help out.

```
// cache the jquery object
 var target =  $('section#coming-soon');
 target.hide();
 // select the specific nav, not all navs
 $('nav:first').mouseenter(function(){
    // only need to show it once on enter
    target.show();
 }).mousemove(function(e) {
    // can't really avoid this unless you want to keep moving it around all the time
    // but show it only once you mouse over
    target.css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
         'top' : e.pageY,
         'left' : e.pageX    
     });
 }).mouseleave(function() {
    target.fadeOut(1300);
  });
```

Comment: I agree with your optimizations, the modal still lags when moving from left to right ( or top to bottom in the fiddle), however.